# Is this a good approach to add margin-left to H2 elements

Tags: html, css

I'd like some (not all) of my H2 headlines to have a left margin of 10px compared to the "regular" H2 lines.
I tried the below code which works but was wondering if there's a better/cleaner way to achieve this. Thanks

HTML

```
<h2 class ="marginleft10px">Blablabla</h2>
```

CSS

```
h2 {
    color: #2970A2;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.marginleft10px {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: That is definitely the simplest way to do it and should work just fine. Typically classes are more semantic though, so you might try a class name that says more about what it represents rather than what it is. Depending on the context it could be anything: .page-title, .section-link, .note-block, etc.

Comment: It seems really okay. But I wouldn't call classes names which implies fixed values inside like `margin5px` or `fontsize12`. Try giving more general names like `.indented` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll keep the god as it is then!

Comment: What else *could* you do except set a `class` attribute, if these `h2` elements are placed in a “totally random” way (as per your comment to an answer)? Was this a serious question? Setting a margin in px units and using a class name that reflects a specific settings are not good practices, but you don’t seem to be interested in such issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a rule that dictates which `h2`s you want to have a `10px` margin? For example are they all child element of some type of element? If its totally random then what you are doing would be a good solution. Otherwise there is probably a better one. Could you post some of your HTML to give us context?

Comment: No worries. Although that begs the question why you randomly change the left-alignment of your headings..

Comment: If that worked, do you mind marking the answer as accepted so this question does not show up as unanswered?